# PrettyPhoto not working on server

Tags: html, lightbox, prettyphoto

I have uploaded my page to me server and I get this error "Image cannot be loaded. Make sure the path is correct and image exist." I have checked all the links  and made sure they are correct. The images do exist. Plus when I do preview in safari with dreamweaver it works perfect. Something has happened between dreamweaver and the server somehow. Any ideas? [Here is the link to the page](http://hotraqs.com/portfolio.html)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either your path to the folder "sat" is wrong or your image names are incorrect. Large images should be in a path like this `images/sat/Alina%20Cerys%20Rutschky_012.JPG`. You should make sure that the folder "sat" is in your "images" folder. I also think that the spaces, `%20`, are a possible reason. Eliminate the spaces in your image names to be sure and use ".jpg", not ".JPG".

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't even think about the spaces. I'm sure that's what is wrong. When I get home tomorrow I will make sure!!!